# Pandas read_csv fillna

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, nan

I have some data that I am reading from a CSV file and one data frame column is recorded on a different time stamp interval (time series data) and I cant get a `df.fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(method = 'bfill')` to work.

If I don't read the CSV file with a `keep_default_na=False` Python fills the gaps with a NaN but I would like the gaps to be blank so I can use the `df.fillna(method = 'ffill')`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#read CSV file
df_raw = pd.read_csv('C:\\desktop\\combinedSP.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True, keep_default_na=False)

df_raw.head()

df_raw2 = df_raw.fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(method = 'bfill')

df_raw2.head()
```

It seems like no matter what I attempt I am not fixing the issue on the column labeled `OAT` :(

[image]

Any tips greatly appreciated, I have the data CSV file [here](https://github.com/bbartling/Machine-Learning-Electric-Data) loaded into my GitHub account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do `keep_default_na=False` this means that what `read_csv` usually would read and parse to NaN it will no longer :

> By default the following values are interpreted as NaN: `‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘n/a’, ‘nan’, ‘null’`.

In this case, it's not parsing the empty string `''` as NaN, it's keeping them as the empty string.

Drop that kwarg and the fillnas ought to work.